# Why does one need to compile two times to have a table of contents in the pdf?

Tags: latex

I am working on a project on Latex but I don't understand why I should compile twice to insert a content table in a PDF document?

Comment: In case you would like to ask your latex questions in French, have a look at https://texnique.fr/osqa/

Comment: thank you, really appreciate it

Comment: can i get your email or some kind of contacts, i have other question if possible?

Comment: You can ask here or at texnique.fr .  I'm sure I'll see your question and I try to answer if I know the solution.

Comment: https://texnique.fr/osqa/questions/9467/determiner-le-caractere-parfait-ou-non-dun-nombre-strictement-positif-latex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile the first time, tex does not yet know which sections will come later in the document. During the first compilation, it collects all the names etc of the sections in the .toc file and in the second compilation, it can then use this information to build the table of contents.